# What's the Azure Table storage equivalent of the T-SQL delete table command?

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I am developing an application that is logging test messages to Azure table storage. I want to clean up the table so that I can quickly see the most recent set of records. Querying in Azure Storage Explorer by specifying the Timestamp takes 30 seconds or so.

What's the fastest way to delete all records in a specific table in Table Storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the entire table.  You may have to wait a few minutes (depending on the size of the table being deleted) before you can recreate the table with the same name.

Comment: Even though deleting the table in Azure Storage Explorer takes less than 10 seconds, you cannot add records or even see the table because you will get an error in your code "table is being deleted". As Mcollier says, you must wait several minutes before your code can recreate the table and add records. After doing this, a query (of all 67 records) took less than a second and the Timestamp query filter was no longer required